# Haskall Monad task

Tags: haskell

I have been given this datatype:

```
data Expr = Num Double| Add Expr Expr | Sub Expr Expr deriving Show
```

and evaluation function:

```
eval :: Expr -> Maybe Double
eval (Num a) = if a<0 then Nothing else Just a
eval (Add a b) = case eval a of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just a' -> case eval b of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just b' -> Just (a' + b')
```

The first task was to rewrite `eval` using `do`:

```
evalDo :: Expr -> Maybe Double
```

so I made this:

```
evalDo (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else Just a
evalDo (Add a b) = do
  eins <- eval a
  zwei <- eval (Add a b)
  return (eins + zwei)
```

The second task was to use `>>=`:

```
evalBd :: Expr -> Maybe Double
evalBd (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else return a
evalBd (Add a b) = _____ a >>= _____ _____ -> _____ _____ >>= \b' -> _____ (a' + ___ )
```

This is my solution:

```
evalBd :: Expr -> Maybe Double
evalBd (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else return a
evalBd (Add a b) = return a >>= \b a -> evalBd a >>= \b' -> Just (a' +  b')
```

but it doesn't work.

And the last task is to implement `Sub`.  The expression `` evalBd (Num 2 `Sub` Num 3) `` should be `Nothing`, and it should look like this:

```
evalBd :: Expr -> Maybe Double
evalBd (Sub a b) = ___ ___ >>= \a' -> ___ ___ >>= \b' -> if a'-b'<0
    then ____ else return (___ ___ ___) `
```

My solution so far is:

```
evalBd (Sub a b) = return a >>= \a' -> Just a' >>= \b' -> if a'-b'<0
    then Nothing else return (Just ___ ___)
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: voting to close. Lacks both focus and clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You said your `evalBd` didn't work.  Did you get an error?  What was it?

Comment: `evalDo` shouldn't need to refer to `eval`. Evaluating `a` alone isn't necessary if `eval` is just going to evaluate `Add a b` as a  whole.

Comment: focus and clarity would be very appreciated. It takes hours to ask such a long question. And the Editor is not as good as it could be, Stack overflow should switch to html and css, as a user I can do nothing to make this text readable.

Comment: evalBd error _______• Couldn't match type ‘p0 -> Expr -> Maybe Double’
                 with ‘Maybe Expr’
  Expected type: Double -> Maybe Expr
    Actual type: Double -> p0 -> Expr -> Maybe Double
• Probable cause: ‘return’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely
    ‘return (\ a b -> evalBd b)’
  In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely
    ‘evalBd a >>= return (\ a b -> evalBd b)’
  In the expression:
    evalBd a >>= return (\ a b -> evalBd b)
      >>= (\ b' -> evalBd (a' + b'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function is fine.

```
eval :: Expr -> Maybe Double
eval (Num a) = if a<0 then Nothing else Just a
eval (Add a b) = case eval a of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just a' -> case eval b of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just b' -> Just (a' + b')
```

Let's think about how to write this using the `Maybe` monad.

```
eval' :: Expr -> Maybe Double
eval' (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else Just a
eval' (Add a b) = ...
```

You know that `a` and `b` are both `Expr`s. Assuming you can evaluate them, you just need to literally add the result of evaluating both.

```
eval' (Add a b) = do
   a' <- eval' a
   b' <- eval' b
   return ???
```

So what do we return? Well, if `a'` and `b'` are `Double`s, we can simply use `+`. But what if `eval' a` returns `Nothing`? That's where the `Maybe` monad comes in: `a + b` only gets *executed* if both calls to `eval'` return `Just` values from which `Double`s could be "extracted". If either returns `Nothing`, the rest of the function short-circuits and returns `Nothing` immediately.

```
eval' (Add a b) = do
   a' <- eval' a
   b' <- eval' b
   return (a' + b')
```

Writing `eval''` with `>>=` is just a matter of desugaring the `do` syntax.

```
eval'' :: Expr -> Double
eval'' (Num a) = if a < 0 then Nothing else Just a
eval'' (Add a b) = eval'' a >>= \a' ->  eval'' b >>= \b' -> return (a' + b')
```

This is possible based on the following rule for "unpeeling" a `do` block:

```
do { x <- a; b }
```

is equivalent to

```
a >>= \x -> do b
```

Comment: Now I know retuern = Just because of the Monad Maybe which holds the double.  The >>= 'operator' hands over the result from (eval'' a) so the next step >>= (___ ___ -> ___ ___) has 3 posible parameters first a and b from (Add a b) and the result from (eval'' a), how do I know which one is handed over. thx

Comment: The lambda is greedy, so the scope of the first argument extends as far as possible. The first `>>=` has two arguments, `eval'' a` and `\a' -> eval'' b >>= \b' -> return (a' + b')`.  The value of `eval'' a` just "hangs around" until `eval'' b` is evaluated and is available in the second lambda `\b -> return (a' + b')`.

Comment: `a` and `b` are likewise in scope throughout, though they are only used for the two calls to `eval''`.